# laravel passing data into view(for a dop down list)

Tags: php, laravel, parameter-passing

I am trying to pass all available designations in register form as follow in laravel 5.7.21 . This is the function in RegisterController

```
 public function showRegistrationForm(){

$designations = Designations::all();

return view('auth.register', compact('designations'));
}
```

these are upper lines of RegisterController

```
 namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\User;
use App\Designation;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\RegistersUsers;

class RegisterController extends Controller
```

This the file structure of my project
[Please click here to view file structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aPPAm.png)

When I try to acces Registraion page via **http://localhost:8081/register**
It generate a error like this
[please click here to view the erro](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yBIFw.png)

Could anyone please help me  slov this hens Im new to laravel. Thanks

Comment: Yes thanks to @shuvo now its working .Thanks all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You spelled `Designations` wrong. It should be `Designation::all()` (as you have imported `use App\Designation;`).

Comment: Ohhh dear you saved my day . Thanks a lot. Thank you.